# 'HubCallerContext' does not contain a definition for 'Request' singnalr .netcore

Tags: .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm using signalr with .Net Core 3.0 and Angular 8

```
public class ConnectionHub : Hub
{
    public ConnectionHub()
    {
    }
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        //get userName, token and other stuff
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

Added in startup.cs:

```
app.UseSignalR(options =>
            {
                options.MapHub<ConnectionHub>("/ConnectionHub");
            });
```

In angular

```
//configure
private connection: any = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:6002/ConnectionHub?userName='abc'")
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
        .build();
//start
this.connection.start()
```

I want to access my custom data sent in query params, but in OnConnectedAsync, the context is following:

[image]

**How can I access query params in OnConnectedAsync() method.**
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#onreconnected) says I can use Context.Request, but in `OnConnectedAsync` it says 'HubCallerContext' does not contain a definition for 'Request'

Comment: Do you have a reference to using async in your override methods on the `Hub` class? I can't find any reference to doing it in such a manner. The `Hub` class doesn't appear to have any async method defined https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj890869(v=vs.100) . I have a feeling you're never returning anything to the base class, hence there not being a `Request` in the context. The documentation shows that you need to return a call to the base class method  `return base.OnConnected();`.

Comment: I doesn't look like you're actually overriding any method within the `Hub` class, from the example you provided. Unless I'm missing something in the docs or the API reference. As it is, it doesn't look like anything is ever going to be sent back to the client. I'd recommend looking at the docs again and checking the API reference to see the methods defined within the `Hub` class, so you can properly override them and complete the loop back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

1. Inherit `ConnectionHub` with `Hub<IHubClients>`
2. get request object by using `Context.GetHttpContext().Request`

so the ConnectionHub class will look like this:

```
 public class ConnectionHub: Hub<IHubClients>
    {
        public ConnectionHub()
        {
        }
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            //get userName, token and other stuff
            var userName = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["userName"];
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: GetHttpContext does not exist here, am I missing something? Using latest SignalR.Core 1.1.0

Comment: You should add also "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" package reference